# Copy IIS SSL Certificate to Exchange 2007

Tags: iis-7, exchange-2007

I have a certificate installed in IIS on my server. I want to use the same certificate in Exchange. All the documentation I can find talks about generating a CSR from PowerShel land importing the reply with PowerShell, but I can't do that because I already have a certificate.
Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the certificate is already installed on the server, you need to assign it to Exchange services; this can be done from the Exchange Management Console (in the "Server Configuration" node), or from the Exchange Management Shell using the `Enable-ExchangeCertificate` cmdlet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997231(EXCHG.80).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export-Exchange Certificate cmdlet to generate a copy of the certificate for importing to another server, client computer, or device.